# Postgresql ltree найти удаленную запись и ее потомков

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create or replace table t1
(
id bigserial,
path ltree,
removed_time timestamp
)
```

Как найти в такой таблице удаленные элементы?

Реализую через pgsql...но там очень тяжело получаеться уверен что можно и sql обойтись.

```
select * from t1 where removed_time is not null
```

но теперь надо найти все потомство удаленных записей и то же исключить из результата (у потомков нет записи об удалении если не удален явно)

Comment: Для начала напишите, что такое потомок, как его вообще искать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С точностью до отрицания (в зависимости от того, нужно ли найти потомков удалённых или наоборот потомков не удалённых):

```
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE NOT 
  (SELECT array_agg(path) FROM t1 WHERE removed_time IS NOT NULL) @> path;
```

ЗЫ: Смотри доки по [ltree](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html), [массивам](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html), [array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html).

Comment: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression - ошибка при такой реализации, пробовал так. Спасибо за совет! Необходимо исключить как удаленные элементы так и их потомков.

Comment: @Yerbol, подправил... мой косяк: попробовал на одной записи, удивился, что работает и выложил...

Comment: Cпасибо. Взял ваш запрос в скобки и исключил из основного select, NOT IN. Хотя и ваш на 100 работает! Буду сравнивать!

Comment: @Yerbol, не совсем понял, что ты имел в виду, но если `SELECT * FROM test
WHERE path NOT IN (SELECT path FROM test WHERE removed_time IS NOT NULL)`, то получается несколько другой результат: https://paste.pound-python.org/show/a6JRhZC77YuTRGfSl8OL/